# Exception ("Cannot access a disposed object") thrown when trying to install packages in IronPython via pip

Tags: python, ironpython

I'm getting the error below when trying to install packages in IronPython via pip. I've tried running cmd as an Administrator and also adding "--user" in the command, but it always leads to the same error.

I get the same error if if I try to install different packages - so it shouldn't be because of any specific package.

I've also tried using the Python Environments window in Visual Studio to get the packages or update PIP, but it fails in the same way.

Is anyone able to advise on what the likely issue is? Alternatively, I'm happy to get an advice on an alternative way to install packages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 356, in prepare_files
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._prepare_file(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\utils\logging.py", line 36, in indent_log
    yield

SystemError: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.
```

Comment: It looks like your image is not working, check out this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post topic to find out how to add an image to your post

Comment: Sorry, I lack the reputation to add an image I believe. I've copied the error as text.

Comment: I see, you can still upload the image to an image hosting site like shows here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/ or like you did you can copy and paste the error